# How do I get all watched video via youtube api

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Can anyone show me the way to get all watched youtube video or check if a video being watched or not by me.

Comment: Welcome to stack.  You will need to show us what you have tried first.  please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The following request will give you a channel's "special" playlists (the ones that are created automatically, like history and watch later), given that you acquired an access token via OAuth beforehand:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

[channels Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

[These steps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) will walk you through the authentication process, in case you still need that step.

After you got the ID of the user's watch history playlist, you can fetch the items with [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) or general information with [Playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists), just like with any other playlist. But remember that these playlists are private to the user, so you have to provide the access token with every call.

Answer (score -1):

The [channels#list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) method will return a JSON with some information about the channel, including the playlist ID for the "uploads" playlist:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=OneDirectionVEVO&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

With the playlist ID you can get the videos with the [playlistItems#list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) method:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUbW18JZRgko_mOGm5er8Yzg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can test those at the end of the documentation pages.

Comment: How do I know which video was watched? Which properties or sign to know that?